# What are the strategies for payload in an event-driven architecture

Tags: microservices, event-driven

I want to know that further details about payloads in an event-driven architecture. I used several online resources and didn't get many details. Please help me to find,

1. Use of the Full Payload.
2. Provide Metadata and an API link with a token to access the Actual Payload, than sending the full data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545336/event-driven-architecture-and-structure-of-events

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, api link rather than full data let's take a sample:

In Amazon, Order Microservice sends a event OrderCancelled and Customer service listen to that event.

Now there could be two ways of sending the event data:

1. Send complete order data in the Event

Pros: Listener services do not need to query Order Service for their functioning.
Cons: Lots of data will be passed in the event even though only 10 % is used. Lots of I/O.

2. Send only order id, cancel reason , customer id , date in the event

Pros: If the data is choosen carefully, much less data is sent in the event.
Cons: If the data is choosen incorrectly, then that means lots of API requests.